# Help identifying a font: Sans with rounded R

Tags: font-identification

[image: Logo]

I've been given the task of recreating the above logo that the client has given me with no original artwork or knowledge of what font has been used. I have used all of the font identifying tools online, including answering questions on the fonts appearance, but with no luck.

I have found [this font](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/bridgeco/gear) which has the same 'R', but none of the other letters are the same.

Comment: It could be a mix of two fonts.

Comment: Might also be a custom typography build - why not just reproduce as vector curves?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a mix of two fonts:

- Akrobat Black: https://www.fontfabric.com/fonts/akrobat/
- Gear Proportion Regular<sup>1</sup>: https://www.dafont.com/gear.font

In the below image you can see the different fonts. The top row is your original image. Second row is Akrobat Black. Third row is Gear Proportion. Final row are Akrobat and Gear properly sized and overlayed in red on top of the original. As you can see, it is pretty close.

[image]

---

<sub>1. You should always try to get a font from its original creator or foundry. Partly because a lot of fonts are stolen, partly because a lot of fonts are re-encoded and/or compressed and thus damaged. The original foundry site is http://bridgeco.jp/home.html, but this is nigh unusable (and only available in Japanese), so here I have opted for a respected font site.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reproduce the logo here, I would suggest you find a typeface close to the logo and then convert it to vector shapes to customize some parts of the word.

I think 'Decima+ Bold' is very close to the original. You just need to work on the 'R' and squish the 'O's

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an exact match, which suggests it might be a custom design, or perhaps an existing font (or a mix of 2) which has been modified.

For a quick and dirty solution you could auto trace it using vector editing software, such as Adobe Illustrator or free software such as Inkscape.

Or, depending on how good your lettering skills are, and how much time you have, it would be possible to manually trace all of the characters with the Pen/Bézier tool in vector editing software.

An example using Inkscape to manually trace over the S and R from the logotype:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I was thinking about doing this before PieBie found the two fonts but I was unsure whether or not this is against copyright or anything (if the fonts hadn't been free for example)? Would be interesting to know in case this sort of thing crops up again. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Alex - I'm afraid I can't answer that, and can't give legal advice. Sorry about that.